# Stop blue LED flashing on BQ Ubuntu phone

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone

I have bluetooth turned off on my BQ 4.5 Ubuntu phone and the blue LED does not flash while using the phone, but when the phone goes into standby mode a blue LED keeps flashing below the top front speaker which is really annoying, especially when I am lying in bed trying to sleep (I usually just flip it round). Is there anyway I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have some notifications waiting. The first indicator (in the left) in the upper side of the screen is an envelope. If you see it green, then you have notifications that you can clear ([page 36 of the manual](https://static-bqreaders.s3.amazonaws.com/file/Ubuntu-Aquaris_E4_5/Manual_Aquaris_E4.5_ubuntu_EN.pdf)) and then, the blue LED will disappear. If the envelope is grey, you will find it empty and there will be another reason.